# Better way to assert a component behavior based on local storage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a class based component in which I look for a variable in localstorage in componentDidMount.

If, it exists I render the children
else, I render a form

How do I write test case for this component? I want to test my component behavior by changing the local storage.

Comment: Testability declines as you depend on global variables and implicit dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer for the readers

```
// My Component
export class Test extends Component {
  public state = { isAvailable: false }
  public componentDidMount() {
    const isAvailable = window.localStorage.getItem("is-agreed") === "true";
    if (isAvailable) {
      this.setState({ isAvailable: true });
      return;
    }
  }
  public render() {
    const template = <p>Not available</p>
    if (this.state.isAvailable) template = this.props.children;
    return template; 
  }
}

// My Test file
describe("Components/Test", () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
  const store = configureStore();

  const getComponent = () => {
    const mockStore = store({ data: { something: something } });
    return mount(
      <Provider store={mockStore}>
        <Test>
          <p id="testChildren">test</p>
        </Test>
      </Provider>,
    );
  };

  // If I mount component in beforeEach I'm not able to change the localStorage since the lifecyle method is called before "it".
  // So I'm mounting the component in each test case after changing the local storage.
  // beforeEach(() => {
  //   wrapper = getComponent(); 
  // });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
  });

  it("should return the children when agreed", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("is-agreed", "true");
    wrapper = getComponent();
    expect(wrapper.exists("#testChildren")).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should return the children when not agreed", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("is-agreed", "false");
    wrapper = getComponent();
    expect(wrapper.exists("#testChildren")).toBeFalsy();
  });
});

// Local storage mock defined globally in setupTests.ts
var localStorageMock = (function() {
  var store: any = {};
  return {
    getItem: function(key: string) {
      return store[key];
    },
    setItem: function(key: string, value: string) {
      store[key] = value.toString();
    },
    clear: function() {
      store = {};
    },
    removeItem: function(key: string) {
      delete store[key];
    },
  };
})();

Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", { value: localStorageMock });
```

Comment: Please add you answer if you have a better solution.